# Java: method().method()

Tags: java

I've made a "Loader" class (self-explanatory, but it loads files from a folder), and since I have to convert the loaded strings to an integer array very commonly, I'd like to add a method to the class that does that.

I've seen the following done before, and use it a lot as well:

```
String s = "";
int length = s.toLowerCase().length();
```

Instead of:

```
String s = "";
String lowercase = s.toLowerCase();
int length = lowercase.length;
```

But when I try to use this method in the Loader class:

```
public int[][] initMatrix() {
    return new int[20][20];
}
```

I get an error (probably obvious why, but I can't wrap my head around it).

What is the correct way of using this?

Edit: Here's the class I intend to use:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Loader {
    public String[] loadStrings(String fileName) {
        String[] ret = null;
        try {
            ret = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toArray(new String[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public int[][] initMatrix() {

    }
}
```

And I try to use:

```
int[][] foo = new Loader().loadStrings().initMatrix();
```

Edit #2: I apologize for the confusing question. I just can't figure out why this one-liner works:

```
char c = "World".toLowerCase().charAt(0);
```

When you System.out.println() this to the console, you end up with a *lowercase* "w", adn only the "w". Therefore, in one line, 2 steps were performed. There are clearly 2 methods doing work.

Why exactly does this happen?

Comment: What I'm generally trying to do is this: `int[][] n = new Loader().loadStrings().initMatrix();`

Comment: @user2310289 that was exactly what i was going to ask...

Comment: This is meaningless `int length = s.toLowerCase().length();`  it is the same as `s.length()`

Comment: "Cannot resolve method 'initMatrix()'

Comment: so where is the code for `loadStrings` and `initMatrix`

Comment: A very confusing question here.

Comment: I know that the example stated above is meaningless, but thats just an example.

Comment: It is much better to describe your exact problem in greater detail and  to show your exact code than to show meaningless code.

Comment: @user3373311 add to question, not in the comments

Comment: Urgh. that looks bad here.

Comment: Yep, all important updates need to be as edits to your original question, not as comments.

Comment: ... so going back to the start, what is your error?

Comment: My "error" is: cannot resolve method 'initMatrix()'

Comment: @user3373311 Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which is normal: a `String[]` has no `initMatrix()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with

```
int[][] foo = new Loader().loadStrings().initMatrix();
```

loadStrings is returning a string array,  The initMatrix is on the Loader class.  You can not chain them together like this.

try

```
Loader loader = new Loader();
loader.loadStrings ();
foo = loader.initMatrix ();
```

If you want to combine these steps you could create a new method in the Loader or call the steps from the constructor

e.g.

```
Public int [][] doMyStuff () {
      loadStrings ();
      return initMatrix ();
   }
```

Comment: My question is: whats the only way I could string them together?

Comment: You do understand what im trying to do right? I'm trying to load a txt file, then create a matrix.

Comment: @user3373311 `Loader loader = new Loader(); loader.loadStrings(); int[][] foo = loader.initMatrix();` or just have `initMatrix` call `loadStrings` if its always a prerequisite.

Comment: Dear 3373311, have a look at my updated answer

Comment: Sorry about that. Thought there was some way of using methods within the same class with others.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably something like this:

```
public class Loader
{
    private String[] strings;

    public Loader loadStrings(final String filename) 
    {
        // initiate, fill "strings", then:
        return this; // Here is the "magic" stuff
    }

    public int[][] initMatrix()
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

But this is a shaky design; for instance, what if you don't `.loadStrings()` before you call `.initMatrix()`? You had better make an `initMatrix(String fileName)` method which calls `loadStrings()` which would then become `private`. That is a solution, there are others.

Comment: In reply to your earlier comment: I think I understand what you meant by String[] not having an initMatrix() method. Though I didn't understand that the first time, thanks for getting that straight for me.